# Segfault - fclose / fopen

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen, fclose

I'm having trouble with my following C code :

```
int main(void){

    FILE* infile = fopen("file","r);
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    unsigned char* buffer = malloc(512);

    while( fread(buffer,512,1,infile) > 0 ){ //reading a file block by block

           if(buffer[0] == 0xff){
               ... //defining variable "name"
               if(fp != NULL)fclose(fp);
               fp = fopen(name,"w+");
               fwrite(buffer,512,1,fp);
           } else if(fp != NULL) {
                   fwrite(buffer,512,1,fp);
           }

    }

}
```

It seems that i can't fopen after fclose using the same pointer, why ? I need my pointer to remain accessible everywhere in the main so i can't declare a new one in my while.

**EDIT: Oh god, problem solved. I was probably super tired. I was compiling the wrong file. Anyway...**

**Thanks, folks !**

Comment: You aren't 'using' the same pointer there. You're just capturing a return value. The segfault is caused by code that you haven't posted here.

Comment: I know this is strange, but if i don't free memory with flose(fp), sgefault does not occurs anymore.

Comment: Please construct the smallest complete program that recreates the problem.

Comment: Note that `fread(buffer, 512, 1, infile)` will return 0 or 1, depending on whether it reads 512 bytes or not.  If you want to read 512 byte blocks only, that's fine.  If you want to read up to 512 bytes at a time, then you need `size_t nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, 512, infile);` and check that you got a non-zero number of bytes read.

Comment: I was wondering the difference between those two, thanks :)

Comment: Tired or not, the code still has some issues.  You'd be well advised to look over the responses you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell why since you aren't showing us all of your code. However, reopening the file should be pretty straightforward:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE* fp = NULL;
  char name[] = "somefile";

  for (;;)
  {
    // do something
    if ((fp = fopen(name, "w+")) == NULL)
      break;
    // do something with the file
    fclose(fp);
    // do something
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `fopen()` returns `NULL`, you have an error—probably shouldn't just break from the loop.

Comment: @DietrichEpp True. I'm just showing that the mere reopening is simple.